# Problem to convert local to UTC during the winter change

Tags: python-3.x

I have an issue when I try to convert Local date/time to UTC date/time during the winter change hour.

I have a list of each date of a given year with 30 min step:
Those dates are in Local time.

Then I am converting them into UTC. I use

```
     local = pytz.timezone("Europe/Paris")
     utc = pytz.timezone("UTC")
     Local_time.astimezone(utc).strftime()
```

It worked well during the first change hour of the year:

Here is the local time (-1 hour)):

```
    2019-03-31 01:00:00    2019-03-31 01:30:00
    2019-03-31 01:30:00    2019-03-31 03:00:00
    2019-03-31 03:00:00    2019-03-31 03:30:00
```

Then the output is:

```
    2019-03-31T00:00:00Z       2019-03-31T00:30:00Z
    2019-03-31T00:30:00Z       2019-03-31T01:00:00Z
    2019-03-31T01:00:00Z       2019-03-31T01:30:00Z
```

So here everything is fine.

But during the second change of hour:

Here is the local time with (+1 hour):

```
    2019-10-27 01:30:00  2019-10-27 02:00:00
    2019-10-27 02:00:00  2019-10-27 02:30:00
    2019-10-27 02:30:00  2019-10-27 02:00:00
    2019-10-27 02:00:00  2019-10-27 02:30:00
    2019-10-27 02:30:00  2019-10-27 03:00:00
```

Then in UTC, it gives me :

```
  2019-10-26T23:30:00Z  2019-10-27T00:00:00Z
  2019-10-27T00:00:00Z  2019-10-27T00:30:00Z
  2019-10-27T00:30:00Z  2019-10-27T00:00:00Z
  2019-10-27T00:00:00Z  2019-10-27T00:30:00Z
  2019-10-27T00:30:00Z  2019-10-27T02:00:00Z
```

I cannot figure out it put off 2 heures everywhere, whereas it should put off only one hour from 03:00 local time ??

Answer (score 0):

I sorry to have asked this questions, I found it by myself actually.

It was quiet obvious..
I used the offset I had in input, with dateutil library

It worked !